# how to interpret google api oauth callback

Tags: ruby, oauth, sinatra, google-api

i'm attempting to gain access to my own gmail account via a sinatra app i'm building.  i'm sending a request to the google api in the form of

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&&scope=https://mail.google.com/+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9393/oauth2callback&access_type=online`

and after I authorize the app via google's web interface, i'm getting what appears to be a correct callback to my own sinatra app.  I'm unclear what I do next in this process.  what i'm getting from the google auth system looks like

`http://localhost:9393/oauth2callback?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY`

I'm then attempting to use the xoauth gem to then query google for information about my account, ie,  https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth
My hope is that the xxxxxx.yyyy string above corresponds in some way to value of
:token as written in the xoauth gem documentation.  when I run a local script to check if things are working correctly, i'm getting a `Invalid credentials (Failure) (Net::IMAP::NoResponseError)`

the documentation i'm using to understand the oauth process is https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

i don't think i'm handling the callback correctly or either i'm misinterpreting what it is.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has only added support for [OAuth 2 authorization for GMail IMAP/SMTP](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview) recently. The library you are using however does [not support this yet](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth/issues/1).

So your options are:

- Improving the library yourself (would be my recommendation)
- Waiting for the library to update
- Falling back to the already deprecated [OAuth 1](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth)